# What condition can you give to this switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, logic, dom-events

This is a switch statement inside a function passed to an event listener keeping track on whether a player has won. there has to be a faster way to compare the winning sequences (in each case). Is there a function or loop that can make this easier. If this was a much bigger game then it would be unbearable to code.
many thanks if you can help :)

```
let keepTrackPlayerTwo = [];
function addSVGs(e) {
    whosGo ++;
    if(whosGo % 2 === 0) {
      this.innerHTML = circle;
      this.removeEventListener("click",addSVGs);
      keepTrackPlayerTwo += this.id; 
     } else{
      this.innerHTML = cross;
      this.removeEventListener("click",addSVGs);
      keepTrackPlayerOne += this.id; 
    } 
    switch(keepTrackPlayerOne) {
 //  Up Top
      case '012': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '021': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '120': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '102': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '201': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '210': console.log('testy'); break;
// Middle 
      case '345': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '354': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '543': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '534': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '453': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '435': console.log('testy'); break;
// bottom
      case '678': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '687': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '786': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '768': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '876': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '867': console.log('testy'); break; 
// left
      case '036': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '063': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '360': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '306': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '630': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '603': console.log('testy'); break;
// middle
      case '147': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '174': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '417': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '471': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '741': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '714': console.log('testy'); break;
// right 
      case '258': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '285': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '582': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '528': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '852': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '825': console.log('testy'); break;
// diagonal left
      case '048': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '084': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '408': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '480': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '840': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '804': console.log('testy'); break;
// diagonal right
      case '246': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '264': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '462': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '426': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '642': console.log('testy'); break;
      case '624': console.log('testy'); break;

    }
}
```

Comment: *"if an array matches"*: there is no array in your code. `+=` is an assignment you do when you have a primitive type, not an array.

Comment: *Sort* `keepTrackPlayerOne` before you compare it…?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off delegating this work to a separate function. You can look at `checkForWinner` -- supported by `defineGroupsOfThree` -- in the demo below to get an idea of what that might look like.

I've coded TicTacToe a couple of times in JavaScript, and I chose to provide this particular version because it's reasonably straightforward (although it might require some study if you're relatively new to JavaScript). I've included extensive comments to clarify how it all fits together.

---

The main idea is keeping the current state of the game in a single `state` object that is the Source of Truth for the app. When the user takes an action, the `updateState` function carries out any changes, and the `repaintDOM` function updates the view. All of this is orchestrated by the click-listener function, `handleBoardClick`.

As alluded to above, `defineGroupsOfThree` creates an array of arrays that we can use to check if someone has won the game. Each of these arrays represents a group of three squares (a row, column, or diagonal) that will win the game for any player that captures all three. So `checkForWinner` checks whether the current state matches any of these winning combinations. (And `checkForTie` just checks whether there are no legal moves remaining.)

Finally, there are two other supporting functions: `isEmptyCell`, which returns true if the user clicks a square that they can legally capture, and `getCharFor`, which is a lookup function that gets the appropriate character to represent a particular player ("X" or "O", or "_" for neither).

---

It would be better (i.e. less error-prone) not to mutate the state object -- that is, to create a brand new state object whenever the state changes, leaving the old one unmolested. But I thought this version might be slightly more straightforward for you to work with; just note that it isn't a best practice. (If you want an exercise, once you understand what this code is doing, you could try updating it to a version that uses immutable state.)

Happy coding.

```js
// Calls `handleBoardClick` when user clicks on `board` div
const boardDiv = document.getElementById("board-div");
boardDiv.addEventListener("click", handleBoardClick);

// Sets initial state for the game
let state = {
  board: [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]], // Three rows, three 0s in each row 
  player: 1, // 1st player (X) has value 1; 2nd player (0) will have -1
  winner: void 0 // Neither player has won yet
}

// Defines groupsOfThree (to be used in `checkForWinner`)
const groupsOfThree = defineGroupsOfThree(state.board);

// Displays initial board
repaintDOM(state);


//
// Defines all game functions, starting with the click listener
//

function handleBoardClick(event){
  const target = event.target;

  // Makes sure user clicked an empty cell before proceeding
  if(isEmptyCell(target)){

    // Updates the state and repaints the DOM
    const {row, col } = target.dataset;
    updateState(row, col, state, groupsOfThree);
    repaintDOM(state);

    // Announces winner if any
    if(state.winner){
      console.log(`The winner is ${getCharFor(state.winner)}`);
      boardDiv.removeEventListener("click", handleBoardClick);
    }
    // Announces tie if board is full with no winner
    else if(checkForTie(state)){
      console.log("Another tie game");
    }
  }
}

function updateState(row, col){
  state.board[row][col] = state.player; // Assigns current player to square
  state.player *= -1; // Works because player numbers are 1 and -1
  state.winner = checkForWinner(state, groupsOfThree); // 1, -1, or undefined
}


function repaintDOM(state){
  // Recalculates all squares' contents (even unchanged ones, a bit wasteful)
  for (let rowDiv of boardDiv.children){
    for (let cellDiv of rowDiv.children){
      const
        // Retrieves row & col info from each square's data attributes
        row = cellDiv.dataset.row,
        col = cellDiv.dataset.col;
        playerValue = state.board[row][col]; // Gets player value from the board
        char = getCharFor(playerValue);
      cellDiv.textContent = char; // Shows `X` or `O` (or leaves default `_`)
    }
  }
  //console.log(`It's ${getCharFor(state.player)}'s turn`);
}

function checkForWinner(state, groupsOfThree){
// (Claim all 3 cells in any group to win)

  // Makes an array of 8 sums (3 for rows, 3 for cols, and 2 for diags)
  const groupSums = groupsOfThree.map(group => { // `map` loops thru groups, gets each sum
    let groupSum = 0;
    for(let {row, col} of group){ // Destructures current array element to row & col
      // Gets the player value from the board (1 or -1) and adds it to the sum
      groupSum += state.board[row][col];
    }
    return groupSum; // Next value returned from `map` (for groupSums array)
  });

  // Now that `groupSums` array is ready, checks all sums for a winner
  // Sum will equal 3 or -3 (ie playerValue * 3) if a player has all 3 cells
  // If so, that player's value is returned to `handleBoardClick`
  for(let groupSum of groupSums){
    if(groupSum == 3){ return 1; }
    else if(groupSum == -3){ return -1; }
  }
}

function checkForTie(state){
  // If any cell in any row still has default value, there is no tie
  for(let row of state.board){
    if(row.some(cellValue => cellValue == 0))
    return false;
  }
  return true; // If we got this far, there are no empty squares: game over
}

function defineGroupsOfThree(board){
  // Creates and returns an array containing 8 arrays (8 "groups")
  // Each group contains 3 objects, representing coordinates for cells on the board
  const groups = [
    // Rows
    [ {row: 0, col: 0}, {row: 1, col: 0}, {row: 2, col: 0} ],
    [ {row: 0, col: 1}, {row: 1, col: 1}, {row: 2, col: 1} ],
    [ {row: 0, col: 2}, {row: 1, col: 2}, {row: 2, col: 2} ],
    // Cols
    [ {row: 0, col: 0}, {row: 0, col: 1}, {row: 0, col: 2} ],
    [ {row: 1, col: 0}, {row: 1, col: 1}, {row: 1, col: 2} ],
    [ {row: 2, col: 0}, {row: 2, col: 1}, {row: 2, col: 2} ],
    // Diags
    [ {row: 0, col: 0}, {row: 1, col: 1}, {row: 2, col: 2} ],
    [ {row: 2, col: 0}, {row: 1, col: 1}, {row: 0, col: 2} ]
  ];
  return groups;
}

function isEmptyCell(eventTarget){
  return eventTarget.classList.contains("cell") && eventTarget.textContent == "_";
}

function getCharFor(playerValue){
  // Player 1 is always "X"; player -1 is "O"
  if(playerValue == 1){ return "X"; }
  else if(playerValue == -1){ return "O"; }
  else if(playerValue == 0){ return "_"; }
  else{ console.log("This is not possible"); }
}
```

```css
div { margin: 0; padding: 1ch; }
.cell { display: inline-block; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<div id="board-div">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- data-attributes for each cell remember the position -->
      <div class="cell" data-row="0" data-col="0"> </div>
      <div class="cell" data-row="0" data-col="1"> </div>
      <div class="cell" data-row="0" data-col="2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell" data-row="1" data-col="0"> </div>
      <div class="cell" data-row="1" data-col="1"> </div>
      <div class="cell" data-row="1" data-col="2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell" data-row="2" data-col="0"></div>
      <div class="cell" data-row="2" data-col="1"></div>
      <div class="cell" data-row="2" data-col="2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```